# writing first row (column headers) to a vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix I have coerced from a realRatingMatrix in recommenderlab package in R. The data contains predictions of ratings between 0-1 for a number of products.

The matrix should contain customer numbers along the rows (row 2 down) so that column 1 header is row label, and product IDs along the columns in the first row from column 2 onwards. The problem I have is when I coerce to a matrix the data structure becomes messy:

EDIT: Link to Github repository [www.github.com/APBuchanan/recommenderlab-model](http://www.github.com/APBuchanan/recommenderlab-model)

```
str(wsratings)
 num [1:43, 1:319] 0.192 0.44 0.262 0.161 0.239 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:319] "X011211" "X014227" "X014229" "X014235" ...
```

The first cell wsratings[1,1] should be labelled as "CustomerNumber" and the remainder of the columns in row 1 should contain the data that is currently held in the above $:chr, but should display as separate variables in the matrix.

From the code below you will see that I've been trying to go about this by inserting the data into two vectors, that I can then call in the dimnames function, but I'm getting something wrong:

```
   setwd("location to pull in data")
#look at using XLConnect package to link straight to excel workbook
library(recommenderlab)
library(xlsx)
library(tidyr)
library(Matrix)
#library(stringer)
data=read.csv("WS1 & WS2 V3.csv",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
#remove rows where number of purchases is <10
df=data[rowSums(data[-1])>=10,]
df<-as.matrix(df)
data.matrix=as(df,"binaryRatingMatrix")
#image(data.matrix)
model=Recommender(data.matrix,method="UBCF")
predictions<-predict(model,data.matrix,n=5)
set.seed(100)
evaluation<-evaluationScheme(data.matrix,method="split",train=0.5,given=5)
Rec.ubcf <- Recommender(getData(evaluation, "train"), "UBCF")
predict.ubcf<-predict(Rec.ubcf,getData(evaluation,"known"),type="topNList")
pred.ubcfratings<-predict(Rec.ubcf,getData(evaluation,"known"),type="ratings")
error.ubcf<-calcPredictionAccuracy(predict.ubcf,getData(evaluation,"unknown"),given=5)
setwd("Location to output data from model")
wsratings<-as(pred.ubcfratings,"matrix")
ratingrows<-c(evaluation@runsTrain)
```

where I've called `colnames2<-c(wsratings[1,2:ncol(wsratings)])` I am expecting the the data from column 2 to the last column, in row 1 to be read into the vector. But when I print the results, it includes rating information as well which is not what I'm after.

`ratingrows<-c(evaluation@runsTrain)` contains the customer numbers that I want to insert below the row label "CustomerNumber".

I'm guessing there's a way of sorting this out with tidyr package, but not so familiar with it. If anyone can provide some advice on how I can clean this all up, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: can you post the reproducible code ? use `dput(wsratings)` and post the result so that we can use that !

Comment: Hi @anup it's a 44x319 matrix so it'll likely exceed the body limit. The 319 columns in row one should each come up in str(wsratings) as a variable, and they are not. They are all contained in "$:chr[1:319] "X011211"...." and so on. The second issue is that the customer IDs have all been dropped. I've loaded these into the variable ratingrows. How do I go about inserting this into wsratings from row2 column 1 down to nrow of column 1?

Comment: I'm sure this is a really straightforward problem, and I am 100% sure I can give you the solution if you provide even a bare minimum example to work with. Just upload a sample dataset on github or anywhere you prefer and that will help us provide solutions better. Right now, it's hard to imagine what you're trying to achieve - even though I'm very convinced it's an easy problem (which makes it more frustrating!)

Comment: @onlyphantom ok I'll see what I can do tomorrow morning, just left the office. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: @onlyphantom please see the repository I've created. https://github.com/APBuchanan/recommenderlab-model
Everything below `ratingrows<-c(evaluation@runsTrain)` is me mucking around trying to solve the problem. I need to extract the customer numbers from the test split of data and drop that into the first column of the matrix - that's my main issue, if the variables can show up correctly as well when `str()` is called that would be fantastic

Comment: @AndrewBuchanan what is it that `data.frame(wsratings)` doesn't do for you? You mentioned that when you call `str(wsratings)` they don't show us as a variable but when you call `str(data.frame(wsratings))` they do. Can you maybe post a screenshot using Excel of what you want the end data structure to look like?

Comment: @onlyphantom Hm interesting, so it does. Well that's fine then - if I convert the matrix back to a data frame then that problem should be resolved. The other issue is that in the first column when I output to excel, I just get from cell A2 downards, numbers going from 1,2,3,4,5...n. This is just a count, and I need the customer numbers here that are in the test split of the data. [screenshot](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img923/5457/eup52z.jpg)

Comment: @AndrewBuchanan hah! glad it was as easy as I imagined it would be! Anyway, if you prefer to stick to the "matrix" structure (without using a dataframe), I posted my answer below. Your code is throwing error because some of the lines were not valid R code. `c(wsratings[0,2:ncol(wsratings)])` in line 27 is not legal, for example. R indexing starts from 1 so whenever you subset 0, there's already a logical error. Hope the answer and my comments help!

Comment: @onlyphantom yes thanks for helping with the first bit - yeah the reference to 0 was me messing around, humouring myself. I've made a reply to your answer - I think your method of going about inserting the column is perfect - it's just the data inserted is not quite correct - these are all product IDs, I need the customer IDs. Thanks again for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the data you gave, I whipped up a solution here.

You said "*I need to extract the customer numbers from the test split of data and drop that into the first column of the matrix - that's my main issue*". The way to extract that is either: `colnames(wsratings)` or `dimnames(wsratings)[[2]]`.

Once you have this vector (length of 320), you want to "drop that to the first column". You're asking for a `cbind()`, but the length of the data you want to bind it contains 43 row. You can't bind them together because the **length of the two elements are not the same or multiples of each other**.

Assuming you have the full dataset and their length matches, then the code would be:

```
customerid <-c("CustomerName", evaluation@runsTrain[[1]])
wsratings <- cbind(customerid, wsratings)
```

This is what I gathered you want, and it yields me the following:

[image]

Comment: Not quite - the numbers you've dropped into column 1 are item IDs - they are the same as the column headers in row one. I believe the customer numbers I need are in the @runsTrain variable of the evaluation object.

Comment: This looks perfect, I will have a go!

Comment: Ok this is working, but I don't think I have the correct data for the customerIDs - I will play around, but given that your method works for inserting the row into the right place I will accept this as an answer. Really appreciate your help!